# Google Apps Script copies a sheet before I create a new one

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This question deals with the same script as my last post.
I added a new feature, which will take the output of the script and send it back to the source workbook as a new sheet with the date it was modified as the name. The purpose is to create an order history. This script and sheet is used multiple times a day. Here is the code:

```
//Copy order to inventory
      newOrderSheet.clearContents();
      var newOrderSheetData = newOrderSheet.getRange(1,1,scoopsData.length, scoopsData[0].length);
          newOrderSheetData.setValues(scoopsData);
      var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(thisSheetId);
          this.newOrderSheet.copyTo(targetSheet).setName(date);
```

This block runs in a switch, with a case for each workbook I need to access. The code in the block runs through each page, pulling the info into the workbook where the script runs. When it loops over a sheet, it gets all the info in the data range and copies that to a sheet in the calling workbook. It then sorts out anything with a zero value, dumps that to the order sheet, then moves on to the next sheet in the target workboook, copies and sorts, next page. It is getting the data fine. I get what I expect.

However, while the top line of this block clears the contents, when I go to look at the sheet that has been copied back into the the data source sheet, the new copied sheet values match the values of the sheet the script was previously run on. To be clear, not the one generated by the script that just ran, but the one generated by the script having run previously. I am happy to provide samples if you need.
Thank you StackOverflow community!

Comment: Questions that look for help with non-working code should included a [mcve]. In Google Apps Script / Google Sheets questions usually this implies to include a link to a demo spreadsheet.

Comment: Please provide samples so we can offer a solution or point you in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your interest and responses. I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was as simple as moving the "newOrderSheet.ClearContents();" line to the top of each case in the switch.

Comment: I know the op was very vague and you would not have been able to tell, so for clarity sake, I will put up the code :

Comment: You can see the line in the OP at the bottom of this case. Sorry for the crappy post. It was very difficult to provide proper output expectation and the output I was getting.